# ifelse condition: is in top n

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Usually when i need a subset on `geom_label()` i use `ifelse()` and i specify a number as below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data = starwars %>% filter(mass < 500)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height, label = ifelse(birth_year > 100, name, NA))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label()
#> Warning: Removed 54 rows containing missing values (geom_label).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But with the dataset i'm working on, i need a dynamic solution, something like `ifelse("birth_year is in top n", name, NA)`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your method, I think using `rank` should work fine, e.g.,

```
ifelse(rank(birth_year) < 10, name, NA))
```

You can use `rank(-birth_year)` if you want it sorted the other way (or, if you're using `dplyr`, `rank(desc(birth_year))`, which will work on non-numeric columns too). You may want to read up on tie methods at `?rank`.

I'd also propose a more general solution: filtering data for the `geom_label` layer. For more complex conditions (e.g., where a `group_by` would come in handy) it will be more straightforward:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height, label = name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(
    data = data %>% 
      group_by(species) %>% 
      top_n(n = 1, wt = desc(birth_year)) # youngest of each species
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? To get top 4 values.

```
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height, label = ifelse(birth_year >= sort(birth_year, decreasing = TRUE)[4], name, NA))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more explicit approach. I assume you want to count the number of characters per birth year, per your example. In this case, we handle the ranking first, then add a column to the original dataset, then plot. The new 'label' field is either blank/NA or has members of the top set. I suppress the pesky missing data warning in the geom_label arguments.

```
data = starwars %>% filter(mass < 500)

# counts names per birthyear, returns vector of top 4
top4 <- data %>% 
  drop_na(birth_year) %>% 
  count(birth_year, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  top_n(4) %>% 
  pull(birth_year)

# adds column to data with the names from the top 4 birth years
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(birth_year %in% top4, name, NA))

# plots data with label, dropping NAs
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mass, y = height, label = label)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]